# Custom ordering of strings

Tags: c#

I have class grades that I need to check if a specific grade is pass or fail. This is the list of grades in order:

1. A
2. A-
3. B+
4. B
5. B-

If `B` is the pass mark, and The student has `B+`, using the normal ordering, if I check if the studentGrade > passMark, then its going to say it is failed because the system orders the strings as follows:

1. A
2. A-
3. B
4. B+
5. B-

How do I setup a custom comparer for ordering a list as the first list in c#?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  A custom comparer is a logical choice to solve the problem, but you need to do some legwork here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting up your letter grades by numeric value?

- A  = 4.0
- A- = 3.7
- B+ = 3.3
- B  = 3.0

and so on....

Then order by numeric value rather than letter grade. `3.0` can be the pass mark.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom class that implements [`IComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx), and use it to do the ordering as needed.

That being said, grades are often handled numerically instead of via string comparisons.  Using a numeric value would make this far simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [sort method of the List<> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) and providing a custom [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) is the way to go (at least one way).

Answer (score 2):

How about an Enum to give them a weight?

```
public enum ComparisonType
{ 
    A = 1, 
    AM = 2, 
    BP = 3,
    B = 4,
    BM = 5
}
```

It makes it easier when creating a custom comparer.

```
public class GradeComparer : IComparer {}
```

After that its a breeze by calling the .Sort() method on your list and voila.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
{     
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
          var grad1 = s1.Replace('+','1').Replace('-','2');
          var grad2 = s2.Replace('+','1').Replace('-','2');             
          if (grad1 > grad2)
              retun 1;
          else if (grad1 < grad2)
              return -1;
          else
              return 0;

    }
}


List<string> list = new List<string>{"A","A+","A-"};

var sortedList = list.OrederBy(o=>o,new MyComparer()).OrderBy(o=>o.Length);
```

Comment: You probably want to replace + with 0, make nothing append "1", and "-" with "2"...